# How to use COUNTIF and SUBTOTAL functions Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have one column (F4:F59) with three different numbers (they will be either "1", "0.5" or "0") and want to only count those that are "1" excluding any hidden rows

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I have spent plenty of time on Google looking for examples, nothing comes close to what I need. I can easily get a count of the whole column, however, it includes the hidden rows

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found another solution to solve this problem, I'm using Google's Data Studio

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that just by using formulas.

You need a script using [isRowHiddenByUser](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#isrowhiddenbyuserrowposition)

As quoted from the site:

> Returns whether the given row is hidden by the user.
>
> ```
> var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
> var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
>
> // Rows start at 1
> Logger.log(sheet.isRowHiddenByUser(1));
> ```

Comment: Thanks. So I just add this script and it will all work?

Comment: No. This is just the method/route you need to follow. **You** need to come up with the actual code/script.

Comment: If I knew how to do that, I wouldn't have posted the question?!

Comment: @woodie If you don't know how to do that, you shouldn't have posted a question. SO is not a free coding service. It is a community of developers helping other developers. Consider taking a JavaScript tutorial and start from there. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/